# Bug with reading data using WebClient

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

In our application we use Silverlight on the client-side. It downloads data from the server using WebClient:

```
WebClient wcGetDataFundSet = new WebClient();
wcGetDataFundSet.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e2) =>
{
    // Do something with the data.
};
wcGetDataFundSet.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(this.uriString));
```

When I open this.uriString in the browser, correct result is displayed.
On another developer's machine everything works just fine. On mine delegate doesn't even fire. Tried using "http://google.com/index.html" and some other URLs. It worked, but e2.Result threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'.
Then I changed code to this and it worked:

```
WebClient wcGetDataFundSet = new WebClient();
wcGetDataFundSet.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e2) =>
{
    // Do something with the data.
};
wcGetDataFundSet.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(this.uriString));
```

Windows XP SP3, Visual Studio 2010 and IE 8 on every machine.
Do you have any ideas where the problem was? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the InnerException of the TargetInvocationException?

Comment: Btw: Don't forget to dispose the WebClient.

Comment: Maybe the WebClient falls out of scope and is garbage-collected before the delegate can be invoked?

Comment: You might be running into the Network Security Access Restrictions in Silverlight: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx

Comment: >>Btw: Don't forget to dispose the WebClient.
There is no "Dispose" method and nothing like it ("Close" or something).

Comment: @Sergey: D'oh. You're right. One place where Silverlight differs from the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is very old and the problem might be solved meanwhile, but i hate threads without an answer...

My Solution was

`DownloadDataAsync`

instead of openReadAsync. The corresponding events are

```
DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)

DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompleteEventArgs e)
```

I only got this Exception while trying to convert the result to string on error (forgot `return` after handling `e.Error`).